# The logic behind 62.5rem for max-width of the row in foundation 5

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I found that as default, foundation does this to style the row:

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 62.5rem;
}
```

however, as a responsive framework, why would it be limited to 62.5rem? The effect is stunning ugly, which is a fixed width box at all time without be able to fluid with the width of the screen. What is the logic behind it? What if I override it with 100%? Will that cause issue with its grid system in general?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

They put that limit because not every day you have a "full width design"; they introduced (in Foundation 6) the modifier class `.expanded`, which added to rows they become full width; If you want to have that behavior in Foundation 5, you have two options:

**1. Create your '.expanded' class**

Foundation limits the `max-width` of the row, so if you add the `.expanded` class to the rows you want to have fluid and add some code like:

```
.row.expanded { max-width: none }
```

You could have it working... maybe will require additional code to have nested rows working properly.

**2. Modify the class / Change the settings**

Foundation is a quite customizable framework, if you're using the SASS version, you could easily modify the variable `$global-width` to be 100%. If you're using the prebuilt version, just locate the `.row` declaration in the code and modify the `max-width` to 100%.

That's it, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

62.5rem is equivalent in Foundation to 1000px. You can easily override it downloading the .css file (which for me is the nicest approach, just plain, fully customizable css) and on line 126 ([foundation 5.5.2](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html)) you have:

```
.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 62.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS3 was introduced a new unit, initially for font sizing, rem stands for "root em" and is relative to the root (html).

A base value of 16px was defined for the majority of browsers, so 1rem equals 16px. Then you got that 62.5rem equals 1000px.

I guess that the `width:100%` rule maybe was a handler error for the browsers that don't support the rem unit.

You can change the width of the row if you want, to do that just remove or comment the max-width rule. Then will render 100% as you want. 
Bootstrap for example sets a 960px width for the container.

In my case I did a modification to the max-width rule, because my layout needed to be 1366px, so I turned that value into 85.375rem.

```
.row {
     width: 100%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-top: 0;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     max-width: 85.375rem; // 1366px width for example
}
```

Take a look at this article to clarify your idea of rem: 
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/

cheers

Comment: you got width 100% AND max-width:85rem.... doesn't your max width overriding the width?

Comment: From my understanding you have to set the width, the max width is to limit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to whatever width you want without hurting anything. It will just make your columns wider.

Typically I use rem-calc(1200) or 100%

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly is the reason to set it at 62.5rem? What's good about it and its logic? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries for that...

Example being

```
@media #{$large-up} {
   $row-width: 100%;
 }
```

It won't "break" anything. It's a variable you can change for a reason.

Comment: You got a great point! and the reason IS exactly the one I do not understand of fixing it...to a specific value

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure you can also start the project with all the parameters already set from the customized foundation builder:
https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/#customizeFoundation

I'm going to start with 1200px width for my content for example so I calculate:
1200/16 = 750rem

It's a good idea anyway to remove any components you are not going to use in the end.

Comment: Also the wider you go, the more work you might have to do later to make the site mobile friendly, keep that in mind. Some text might end up looking great at full width but then when you go to fit it on mobile it might be too large or too small.